# The JAR file C:\...Tomcat-8.0\lib\servlet-api.jar has no source attachment

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, attachment

I did Ctrl+Click on `HttpServlet` to see source code of `HttpServlet`, but it gave me this error:

[image: Error when I click "Ctrl + click" on httpservlet]

How to fix this? It says, I should download "servlet-api.jar", but when I try to download, I can not understand which one should I download? There are lot of servlet-api.jar files.

Answer (score 7):

The source code is not necessarily specific to the Servlet API, but to the Servlet Implementation itself. In your particular case, Tomcat is the Servlet Implementation. So, you need to head to its [homepage](https://tomcat.apache.org/) to find download links to the source code. Usually it's at the same place as where you downloaded the binaries.

Tomcat 8.0 download page is [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi), if you scroll to bottom, then you should see those links:

> #### Binary Distributions
>
> - Core:
>
>   - [zip](http://ftp.tudelft.nl/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.32/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.32.zip) <-- this is Tomcat server itself.
>   - ...
>
> #### Source Code Distributions
>
> - ...
> - [zip](http://ftp.tudelft.nl/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.32/src/apache-tomcat-8.0.32-src.zip) <-- this contains the source code.

Download the source code zip, put it somewhere in your file system (I usually put it in Tomcat installation folder; do note that you do not need to extract it!). Finally, press <kbd>Attach Source</kbd> button in Eclipse and point to that source code zip file.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! this is a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

If this maven based project , you just select the dependency in the Package Explorer, right click and then select "Attach resource"

[image]