# Find Implementation of javax.servlet-api (ServletContainerInitializer and ServletContext)

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, servlets, spring-tool-suite

`ServletContainerInitializer` and `ServletContext` is part of `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar.`

1)
I know `SpringServletContainerInitializer` implements `ServletContainerInitializer`. Both the servlet api jar and spring-web jar is part of the maven dependency and is shown under maven dependencies of the project.

When I did `CTRL+T` on the interface, it is not showing the implementation. How to make eclipse show it ?

2) i) How to make eclipse know about Tomcat source (a reference would suffice) and to see the implementation of `ServletContext` ?
ii) Can you also point me to the tomcat site where I can search for implementations of interfaces ?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you do Ctrl+Shift+T to open ServletContainerInitializer, do you see multiple occurrences? Which one exactly did you open? Which one exactly does Spring have declared as dependency? Those have to match in order to appear in Ctrl+T.

Comment: Your second question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/q/35713815 In the future, ask one question per Question, that makes it easier curating questions.

Comment: @BalusC I have 2 occurrences. One is in `javax.servlet` of `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar`.Another one is in `javax.servlet` of `tomcat-embed-core-7.0.53.jar`. Both have the same package name! In `spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.pom`, I could see the dependency for `javax.servlet`,  `javax.servlet-api`,`3.0.1`.Because of package collision, Ctrl+T cannot find the implementation ? Seems like Ctrl+T does not consider dependency details. Looks like build path is the only criteria ? What is the internal mechanism it uses to find the implementations of an interface in case of package collision ?

Comment: Ctrl+T should work on the occurrence in javax.servlet-api (because Spring is using that as dependency).

Comment: @BalusC Can you please have a look at the screenshot. Ctrl+T on the interface does not show the implementation (may be because of package collision) ? But at least Ctrl+T on the implementation should be showing the interface right (based on the dependency) ? My main interest is Ctrl+T on the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the maven goal mvn dependency:sources from the root of your project. It will download all the available sources for your project dependencies

Comment: It is more of an eclipse question,I guess. I have the sources of servlet-api as well as spring-web. Eclipse is not able to find the implementation `SpringServletContainerInitializer` of the interface `ServletContainerInitializer`.